# Which way of solving from nonlinear control to choose?

Tags: differential-equations, nonlinear, control-systems, process-control

I have a nonlinear system:

\begin{cases} x'=f(x)+u \\ y=f(x) \end{cases}

where $f(x)$ - gradient of some one-extremal function (for example $f=e^{-(x)^2}$), i.e. $\frac{df}{dx}$.

I want to construct a continuous control $u$ that ensures the following condition:

$y(t)=y(0) e^{-\beta t}, \beta>0$

Which method (available in Mathematica) should I use for the solution: Asymptotic Output Tracking, Feedback Linearization, Asymptotic Output Tracking with Estimator, or something else?

I would appreciate your help in choosing the most appropriate method.

Comment: @MarcoB

I edit question.

Comment: Thank you, that’s clearer now. I’ve made a further edit. Please check if I’ve captured your intentions.

Comment: @MarcoB

Yes you are right. Thank you for the revision done.