# Asymptotic Output Tracking: Code Issues

Tags: differential-equations, nonlinear, control-systems, asymptotics, process-control

My question is a continuation of the topic [Which way of solving from nonlinear control to choose?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/239592/which-way-of-solving-from-nonlinear-control-to-choose), and in the future I plan to expand this question.

I want to try to apply this article https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-10/nonlinear-control-systems/asymptotic-output-tracking.html but for a different ODE or ODE system.

**Edit:** Take system of ODE with output $y$ for example:

$\begin{cases} \frac{dx}{dt}=H \cdot \sin(t)+u \\ \frac{dH}{dt}+h \cdot H = \frac{df}{dt} \\ y=x \end{cases} $

where $f=-x^2$, $x$ and $H$ - variables, $h$ - constant, $y$ - output.

To begin with Asymptotic Output Tracking, we transform system of ODE into the affine state-space https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AffineStateSpaceModel.html.

Here is my code.

```
Clear["Derivative"]

ClearAll["Global`*"]

pars = {xs = -1, h = 1}

f = -x^2

ode = {x', H'} == {H Sin[t] + u, f' - h H}

asys = AffineStateSpaceModel[
  NonlinearStateSpaceModel[{ode[[2]], {x}}, {{x, xs}, {H, 
     1}}, {u}]]
```

I would be grateful for any help and support in resolving the issue.

**NEW EDIT:**
This is my code for $f=\log (\text{sech}(1-x(t)))$ and two outputs `y={D[f, x[t]], x[t]}`

```
Clear["Derivative"]

ClearAll["Global`*"]

pars = {xs = -1, xe = 1, h = 1, \[Beta] = 1}

f = Log[Sech[(x[t] - xe)]]

assm = AffineStateSpaceModel[{x'[t] == H[t] Sin[t] + u[t], 
   H'[t] + h H[t] == D[f, t]}, {{x[t], xs}, {H[t], 0}}, 
  u[t], {D[f, x[t]], x[t]}, t]

ref = Exp[-\[Beta] t]

pars1 = {Subscript[p, 1] -> -1}

fb = AsymptoticOutputTracker[assm, ref, {Subscript[p, 1]}] /. pars1

csys = SystemsModelStateFeedbackConnect[assm, fb]

{xe, OutputResponse[{csys}, {0, 0}, {t, 0, 10}]}

Plot[%, {t, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All]
```

**NEW PROBLEM (16.02.2021):**

```
 Clear["Derivative"]

ClearAll["Global`*"]

f = -((x[t] + \[Alpha]1 Sin[\[Omega]1 t] - 
       xe)^2 + (y[t] + \[Alpha]2 Sin[\[Omega]2 t] - ye)^2)

asys = AffineStateSpaceModel[{x'[t] == 
     f \[Alpha]1 Sin[\[Omega]1 t] + u1[t], 
    y'[t] == f \[Alpha]2 Sin[\[Omega]2 t] + u2[t]}, {{x[t], 
     xs}, {y[t], ys}}, {u1[t], u2[t]}, {f \[Alpha]1 Sin[\[Omega]1 t], 
    f \[Alpha]2 Sin[\[Omega]2 t]}, t] // Simplify

pars1 = {Subscript[r, 1] -> (-(\[Alpha]1 Sin[\[Omega]1 t])^3), 
  Subscript[r, 2] -> (-(\[Alpha]2 Sin[\[Omega]2 t])^3), 
  Subscript[p, 1] -> -5, Subscript[p, 2] -> -5}

pars = {\[Alpha]1 = 0.35, \[Omega]1 = 1, \[Alpha]2 = 0.35, \[Omega]2 =
    2, xs = -1, xe = 1, ys = 2, ye = -2, h1 = 1, h2 = 1}

fb = AsymptoticOutputTracker[
    asys, {Subscript[r, 1], Subscript[r, 2]}, {Subscript[p, 1], 
     Subscript[p, 2]}] /. pars1 // Simplify
```

**ERROR:**

```
AsymptoticOutputTracker::dmat2: The decoupling matrix {{0.,Sin[t] (<<1>>)},{0.,Sin[2 t] (<<1>>)}} has no columns with two or more nonzero elements, and hence the extension algorithm fails.

AsymptoticOutputTracker::dmat2: The decoupling matrix {{0.,Sin[t] (<<1>>)},{0.,Sin[2 t] (<<1>>)}} has no columns with two or more nonzero elements, and hence the extension algorithm fails.
```

**What is this error related to?**

Comment: Apparently you cross posted it at https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/40211, and it appears to me that you are not quite sure what to ask. I have attempted an answer by party reading between the lines. For any follow-up please make your question more clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Updated answer**

Use the chain rule and express $f'[t]$ in terms of $x'[t]$. Then the two equations can be solved for $x'[t]$ and $H'[t]$. [`AffineStateSpaceModel`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AffineStateSpaceModel.html) (including [`NonlinearStateSpaceModel`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NonlinearStateSpaceModel.html) and [`StateSpaceModel`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StateSpaceModel.html)) can handle this automatically.

The model:

```
assm = AffineStateSpaceModel[{x'[t] == H[t] Sin[t] + u[t], 
 H'[t] + h H[t] == D[-x[t]^2, t]}, {x[t], H[t]}, u[t], x[t], t];
```

The signal the output should track:

```
ref = x0 Exp[-β t] t^3; (* just the exponential term is rather bland *)
```

The feedback controller:

```
fb = AsymptoticOutputTracker[assm, ref, {p1}]
```

> $t^2 \text{x0} e^{\beta  (-t)} (\text{p1} t+\beta  t-3)-\text{p1} x_1(t)+\sin (t) x_2(t)$

The closed-loop system:

```
csys = SystemsModelStateFeedbackConnect[assm, fb];
```

Simulate by substituting some values:

```
{ref /. {β -> 1, x0 -> 1}, OutputResponse[{csys, x0} /. {β -> 1, x0 -> 1, p1 -> -1}, {0}, t
    ][[1]]} // Simplify // Quiet;
Plot[%, {t, 0, 15}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

**Case when $f$ is $e^{-(x-1)^2}$ and $x$ is the output**

```
assm = AffineStateSpaceModel[{x'[t] == H[t] Sin[t] + u[t], 
    H'[t] + h H[t] == D[Exp[-(x[t] - 1)^2], t]}, {x[t], H[t]}, u[t], 
   x[t], t];

ref = x0 Exp[-β t] t^3;

fb = AsymptoticOutputTracker[assm, ref, {p1}];

csys = SystemsModelStateFeedbackConnect[assm, fb];

{ref /. {β -> 1, x0 -> 1}, 
   OutputResponse[{csys, x0} /. {β -> 1, x0 -> 1, h -> 1, p1 -> -1}, 
     {0}, {t, 0, 10}][[1]]} // Simplify ;
Plot[%, {t, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

**Previous answer**

The model:

```
assm = AffineStateSpaceModel[{{Exp[-x[t]^2]}, {{1}}, {Exp[-x[t]^2]}}, x[t], u[t], y[t], t];
```

The signal the output should track:

```
ref = x0 Exp[-β t] t^3; (* just the exponential term is rather bland *)
```

The feedback controller:

```
fb = AsymptoticOutputTracker[assm, ref, p]
```

> $\frac{t^2 \text{x0} (p t+\beta  t-3) \left(-e^{x(t)^2-\beta  t}\right)+p+2 e^{-x(t)^2}
>    x(t)}{2 x(t)}$

The closed-loop system:

```
csys = SystemsModelStateFeedbackConnect[assm, fb];
```

Simulate by substituting some values:

```
{ref /. {β -> 1, x0 -> 1}, OutputResponse[{csys, x0} /. {β -> 1, x0 -> 1, p -> -1}, {0}, t
    ][[1]]} // Simplify // Quiet;
Plot[%, {t, 0, 15}, PlotRange -> All]
```

> [image]

Comment: What if I want to use not $x(t)$ as an output, but $\frac{df}{dx}$ or $x(t)+H(t)$ for example

Comment: Can this code be extended to a multi-input system?

Comment: The answer to all your questions is yes. I was able get the simulation working by switching to a numeric one or changing the reference to $x0 e^{\beta  (-t)}$. For multiple inputs see https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AsymptoticOutputTracker.html#1596835507.

Comment: Try to use function $f=e^{-(x-1)^2}$, and also $x(t)$ as an output. For some reason, the solution for $x(t)$ does not transition from state $xs=-1$ to state $1$.

Comment: I have no idea what you are referring to. I have added the case with $f=e^{-(x-1)^2}$ and $x$ as output. Could you take it from here?

Comment: Oh, i'm sorry, i did not formulate the question correctly. Select $\frac{df}{dx}$ as an output and see what happens to the $x$ variable.

Comment: If $\frac {d f} {d x}$ is the output, [`AffineStateSpaceModel`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AffineStateSpaceModel.html) cannot be constructed as it does not support descriptor systems. Again, I'm not following what you mean by 'see what happens to the $x$ variable.' I am inclined to think that if you formulate the problem correctly, you will be able to solve what you are after.

Comment: Dear Suba Thomas, please see my new edit. https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/239610/asymptotic-output-tracking-code-issues

Is it correct? That's what i mean.

Comment: Yes, the results seem correct. If we evaluate `Plot[Evaluate@Flatten@{ref,OutputResponse[{csys},{0},{t,0,10}]},{t,0,10},PlotRange->All]` we see that `D[f,x[t]]` tracks `ref` and  `x` goes from -1 to 1.

Comment: I can't get a workable program if I use as output $H(t) sin(t)$

`Infinity::indet: Indeterminate expression 0 ComplexInfinity encountered.`

`Infinity::indet: Indeterminate expression 0 ComplexInfinity Tanh[2] encountered.`

`OutputResponse::symbs2: Cannot simulate response of the NonlinearStateSpaceModel and initial conditions that contain symbolic parameter(s) {Indeterminate}.`

Comment: I see that `SystemsModelStateFeedbackConnect[assm, fb] // Simplify` removes the spurious artifacts?

Comment: Please, see my edit. ERROR: `NDSolve::ndsz: At t == 7.999998897029152`, step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected.`

Comment: It's just the nature of the system. This can be avoided by doing something like `OutputResponse[{csys, {10, 0}}, 0, {t, 0, 100}]`. (Use `FullSimplify` instead of `Simplify` and also get the symbolic solution to the first state to see why your edit had problems.)

Comment: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/249216/asymptotic-output-tracking-compensator-properties