# Comparison of NDSolve and Asymptotic Output Tracking results: Problem identified

Tags: dynamic, nonlinear, control-systems, asymptotics, process-control

My question is a continuation of the topic:

[Asymptotic Output Tracking: Code Issues](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/239610/asymptotic-output-tracking-code-issues)

**Edit:** Take system of ODE for example:

$\begin{cases} \frac{dx}{dt}=H \cdot \alpha \sin(\omega t)+\alpha \omega \cos(\omega t) \\ \frac{dH}{dt}+\cdot H = \frac{df}{dt} \end{cases} $

With output $y=H \cdot \alpha \sin(\omega t)+\alpha \omega \cos(\omega t)$

First, I solve the equation with NDSolve and notice an interesting detail:

```
Clear["Derivative"]

ClearAll["Global`*"]

pars = {xs = -2, xe = 0, α = 0.35, ω = 1, y = 1}

f = -(x[t] - xe)^2 + y

sys = NDSolve[{x'[t] == 
    H[t] α Sin[ω t] + D[α Sin[ω t], t], 
   H'[t] + H[t] == D[f, t], x[0] == xs, H[0] == 0}, {x, H}, {t, 0, 
   500}]

Plot[{Evaluate[x[t] /. sys], xe + α Sin[ω t]}, {t, 0, 
  150}, PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 100]
```

This is solution:
[image]

And this output $y$. It can be seen that the system should ideally strive for $\alpha \omega \cos(\omega t)$:

```
Plot[{Evaluate[
   H[t] α Sin[ω t] + D[α Sin[ω t], t] /. 
    sys], Evaluate[D[α Sin[ω t], t]]}, {t, 490, 500}, 
 PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 100]
```

[image]

The idea arose to solve a kind of "inverse problem". To do this, I use the *Asymptotic Output Tracking*, as the output of the system $y=H \cdot \alpha \sin(\omega t)+\alpha \omega \cos(\omega t)$ and $x$, and as the reference model $r_1=\alpha \omega \cos(\omega t)$ for $y$, and this is what I got:

```
(***)

Clear["Derivative"]

ClearAll["Global`*"]

f = -(x[t] - xe)^2 + y

asys = AffineStateSpaceModel[{x'[t] == 
     H[t] α Sin[ω t] + D[α Sin[ω t], t] + 
      u[t], H'[t] + H[t] == D[f, t]}, {{x[t], xs}, {H[t], 0}}, {u[
     t]}, {H[t] α Sin[ω t] + 
     D[α Sin[ω t], t], x[t]}, t] // Simplify

pars1 = {Subscript[r, 1] -> D[α Sin[ω t], t], 
  Subscript[p, 1] -> -1}

fb = AsymptoticOutputTracker[
   asys, {Subscript[r, 1]}, {Subscript[p, 1]}] // Simplify

pars = {xs = -2, xe = 0, α = 0.35, ω = 1, y = 1}

csys = SystemsModelStateFeedbackConnect[asys, fb] /. pars1 // Simplify

plots = {OutputResponse[{csys}, {0, 0}, {t, 0, 100}]}

Plot[{Evaluate[Join[plots, {Subscript[r, 1]} /. pars1]], xe}, {t, 0, 
  100}, PlotRange -> Full]
```

[image]

**Problem.** Despite the fact that the output $y$ stabilizes around the required reference signal $r_1$, the variable $x$ (*orange*) does not budge, as when solving the system using NDSolve.

I would be grateful for help in understanding the solution to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you gave a constant reference $r_1$ to [`AsymptoticOutputTracker`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AsymptoticOutputTracker.html). I also increased the decay rate $p_1$ for it to converge faster. With essentially these changes, in the side-by-side plots we see that the first output tracks $r_1$.

```
pars = {xs = -2, xe = 0, α = 0.35, ω = 1, y = 1};

f = -(x[t] - xe)^2 + y;

asys = AffineStateSpaceModel[{x'[t] == 
 H[t] α Sin[ω t] + D[α Sin[ω t], t] + 
  u[t], 
H'[t] + H[t] == D[f, t]}, {{x[t], xs}, {H[t], 0}}, {u[
 t]}, {H[t] α Sin[ω t] + 
 D[α Sin[ω t], t], x[t]}, t] // Simplify

pars1 = {Subscript[r, 1] -> D[α Sin[ω t], t], Subscript[p, 1] -> -10};

fb = AsymptoticOutputTracker[asys, {Subscript[r, 1]} /. pars1, {Subscript[p, 1]}] // Simplify

csys = SystemsModelStateFeedbackConnect[asys, fb] /. pars1 // Simplify;

plots = OutputResponse[{csys}, {0, 0}, {t, 0, 100}][[1]]
Plot[#, {t, 0, 100}, PlotRange -> Full] & /@ {plots, Subscript[r, 1] /. pars1}
```

[image]

Comment: Please see what happens to the output $x$ coordinateю

Comment: The first state $x$ keeps decreasing and the second $H$ settles around $-0.1$? The controller causes the output to track the reference. The state trajectories are what cause that to happen.

Comment: That's right, the output $y$ must follow the trajectory $r_1$, but the $x$-coordinate must transition their states from $x_s=-2$ to the state $x=0$.

Comment: Why should that be? The equation for $x1$ from `csys` is `DSolve[{x1'[t] == (0.5 + 4.5 (-0.1))/x1[t]}, x1[t], t]`.