# Asymptotic Output Tracking - How to Track?

Tags: differential-equations, dynamic, nonlinear, control-systems

[Asymptotic Output Tracking: Code Issues](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/239610/asymptotic-output-tracking-code-issues)

Abstract state-space:

\begin{cases} \dot{x_1}=x_3 \\ \dot{x_2}=-x_2+\frac{df}{dt} \\ \dot{x_3}=-x_3+x_2 \cdot \alpha \sin(\omega t) + u \\ \dot{x_4}=-x_4+x_2 \cdot (\frac{16}{\alpha^2}(\sin(\omega t)^2-\frac{1}{2})) \\ \frac{1}{k}\dot{x_5}=-x_5+\dot{x_1} \end{cases}

where, $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5$ - variables; $f=-(x_1+\alpha \sin(\omega t)-1)^2$; $\alpha, \omega,k$ - positive constants ($k>>1$)

**Task:** synthesize a control law that asymptotically tracks the output $y=\tanh(k \cdot x_4)+1$ to zero ([Asymptotic Output Tracking](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-10/nonlinear-control-systems/asymptotic-output-tracking.html)), i.e.
$ y \rightarrow 0$

According to the Mathematica, the system is controllable only in the case under consideration (if you put the control signal in other equations, it becomes uncontrollable), but unobservable.

```
Clear["Derivative"]
ClearAll["Global`*"]

Needs["Parallel`Developer`"]

S[t] = \[Alpha] Sin[\[Omega] t]
M[t] = 16/\[Alpha]^2 (Sin[\[Omega] t]^2 - 1/2)

f = -(x1[t] + S[t] - 1)^2

Parallelize[
 asys = AffineStateSpaceModel[{x1'[t] == x3[t], 
     x2'[t] == -x2[t] + D[f, t], x3'[t] == -x3[t] + x2[t] S[t] + u[t],
      x4'[t] == -x4[t] + x2[t] M[t], 
     1/k x5'[t] == -x5[t] + D[x1[t], t]}, {{x1[t], xs}, {x2[t], 
      0}, {x3[t], 0}, {x4[t], 0}, {x5[t], 0}}, {u[
      t]}, {Tanh[k x4[t]] + 1}, t] // Simplify]
ControllableModelQ[asys]
ObservableModelQ[asys]
```

I learned how to use this command, but I had a problem with where to place the input control signal $u$ so that the numerical analysis of the closed-loop synthesized feedback system takes place without singularities.

I would be grateful for a hint. I will try to work out all the proposed solutions immediately in Mathematica. Please help, this is urgent.

Comment: I don't quite follow your question fully. Is this what you are looking for `AsymptoticOutputTracker[asys, 0, {-1, -2, -3, -4, -5}]`? I just randomly chose those negative poles.

Comment: @SubaThomas 

no, the problem is not the choice of poles. The problem lies in the numerical assessment of the dynamics of outputs. There is a singularity there.

Comment: @SubaThomas, and what does the message mean  `AsymptoticOutputTracker::drvro: The dimensions of the decay rates {Subscript[p, 1]} are inconsistent with the vector relative order {2}.` and what to do with it ???

Comment: Since you seem to be using [`AsymptoticOutputTracker`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AsymptoticOutputTracker.html) a lot, it would be very helpful for you to know the underlying theory. The message says that you need to specify 2 decay rates.