# Asymptotic Output Tracking: Compensator properties

Tags: differential-equations, dynamic, nonlinear, control-systems, asymptotics

[Asymptotic Output Tracking: Code Issues](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/239610/asymptotic-output-tracking-code-issues)

The question is, rather, of a theoretical nature (practical applications can be viewed in the topic at the link).

Asymptotic Output Tracking is said to be based on the FeedbackLinearize command which has different Compensator properties.

**Question:**
What is *"DecouplingMatrix"*, what is its meaning and how can it be "pulled out" after synthesizing a linearizing feedback signal?

**EDIT:**

```
Clear["Derivative"]

ClearAll["Global`*"]

s[t] = \[Alpha] Sin[\[Omega] t]; 
m[t] = 16/\[Alpha]^2 (Sin[\[Omega] t]^2 - 1/2);

f = Exp[-(x[t] - 0)^2];

asys = AffineStateSpaceModel[{x'[t] == G[t], 
     G'[t] + G[t] == D[f, {x[t], 1}] + u[t], 
     H'[t] + H[t] == D[f, {x[t], 2}], 
     1/k X'[t] + X[t] == x'[t]}, {{x[t], xs}, {G[t], 0}, {H[t], 
      0}, {X[t], 0}}, {u[t]}, {X[t] - G[t]}, t] // Simplify;

\[ScriptCapitalF] = 
  FeedbackLinearize[
   asys, {{Subscript[z, 1], Subscript[z, 2], Subscript[z, 3], 
     Subscript[z, 4]}, {Subscript[v, 1], Subscript[v, 2]}}];

{\[ScriptCapitalF]["ResidualSystem"], 
  NonlinearStateSpaceModel@\[ScriptCapitalF]["LinearSystem"]};


\[ScriptCapitalF]["InverseStateTransformation"];



\[ScriptCapitalF]["DecouplingMatrix"];
```

Comment: From the 'Details and Options: "The feedback compensator is essentially a transformation between $\hat{u}$  and $\underline{u}$ given by $\hat{u}=\alpha \left(\hat{x}\right)+\beta \left(\hat{x}\right).\underline{u}$, where $\beta \left(\hat{x}\right)$ is the decoupling matrix."

Comment: The table below that explains how to obtain it. And the specific examples for this is in the [`Compensator Properties`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FeedbackLinearize.html#1192128182) subsection under Scope.

Comment: @SubaThomas how to extract this matrix in the context of the asymptotic output tracking command?

Comment: I'm not quite sure why you explicitly need the decoupling matrix for [`AsymptoticOutputTracker`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AsymptoticOutputTracker.html), but you can get the decoupling matrix computed in the intermediate steps of `AsymptoticOutputTracker[sys]` using `FeedbackLinearize[ssm, Automatic, "DecouplingMatrix"]`.

Comment: @SubaThomas By the way, if you have the time and the opportunity to demonstrate this with a simple example - could you frame your comment in the form of an answer?

Comment: @SubaThomas I need to look at its structure and study some of its properties. Thank you for your help! We can get example from here: https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-10/nonlinear-control-systems/asymptotic-output-tracking.html

Comment: It's a bit of computation post `FeedbackLinearize` and that's why there's a dedicated function for it. I will try and make some time to add an example here within a few days.

Comment: @SubaThomas As soon as you are ready, let me know as soon as possible. I switched to other questions, but I can come back to this right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the system [here](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-10/nonlinear-control-systems/asymptotic-output-tracking.html):

```
asys = AffineStateSpaceModel[{{-Subscript[k, 1] Sqrt[
      Subscript[x, 
       1]], -((Subscript[k, 2] Subscript[x, 2])/(1 + 
          Subscript[x, 2])^2)}, {{1, 
     1}, {(Subscript[c, B1] - Subscript[x, 2])/
      Subscript[x, 1], (Subscript[c, B2] - Subscript[x, 2])/
      Subscript[x, 1]}}, {Subscript[x, 1], 
    Subscript[x, 2]}, {{0, 0}, {0, 0}}}, {{Subscript[x, 1], 
    25.05}, {Subscript[x, 2], 9}}, {{Subscript[u, 1], 
    1}, {Subscript[u, 2], 1}}];
```

And feedback linearize it:

```
ℱ = 
 FeedbackLinearize[
  asys, {{Subscript[z, 1], Subscript[z, 2]}, {Subscript[v, 1], 
    Subscript[v, 2]}}];
```

There are no residual dynamics and the system is completely linearized:

```
{ℱ["ResidualSystem"], NonlinearStateSpaceModel@ℱ["LinearSystem"]}
```

> [image]

And this is the inverse state transformation:

```
ℱ["InverseStateTransformation"]
```

> $\left\{z_1\to x_1,z_2\to x_2\right\}$

If we want the first output $z_1$ to track a signal $r_1[t]$ with dynamics $p_1$ it must satisfy the equation
$$(z_1'(t)-r_1'(t))-p_1 \left(z_1(t)-r_1(t)\right)==0$$

From the transformed linear system we see that $z_1'(t)==v_1(t)$ and from the inverse state transformation we see that $z_1(t)==x_1(t)$.

Thus the equation becomes:

$$(v_1(t)-r_1'(t))-p_1 \left(x_1(t)-r_1(t)\right)==0$$

And we get a similar equation for the second output:

$$(v_2(t)-r_2'(t))-p_2 \left(x_2(t)-r_2(t)\right)==0$$

We can write $v_1(t)$ and $v_2(t)$ in terms $u_1(t)$, $u_2(t)$, $x_1(t)$ and $x_2(t)$ using the "InverseFeedbackTransformation" property which contains the decoupling matrix. Then from the above two equations $u_1(t)$ and $u_2(t)$ can be solved.

```
eqns={(Subscript[v, 1] - D[Subscript[r, 1][t], t]) - 
    Subscript[p, 1] (Subscript[x, 1] - Subscript[r, 1][t]) == 
   0, (Subscript[v, 2] - D[Subscript[r, 2][t], t]) - 
    Subscript[p, 2] (Subscript[x, 2] - Subscript[r, 2][t]) == 
   0} /. ℱ["InverseFeedbackTransformation"]
```

> $\left\{k_1 \left(-\sqrt{x_1}\right)-p_1
>    \left(x_1-r_1(t)\right)-r_1'(t)+u_1+u_2=0,\\\frac{u_1
>    \left(c_{\text{B1}}-x_2\right)}{x_1}+\frac{u_2
>    \left(c_{\text{B2}}-x_2\right)}{x_1}-\frac{k_2 x_2}{\left(x_2+1\right){}^2}-p_2
>    \left(x_2-r_2(t)\right)-r_2'(t)=0\right\}$

Let's assume that the two signals to be tracked are constant:

```
signals = {Subscript[r, 1][t] -> Subscript[r, 1], Subscript[r, 2][t] -> Subscript[r, 2]};
```

Now we can solve for $u_1(t)$ and $u_2(t)$ (the negative sign is for negative feedback):

```
ans = -{Subscript[u, 1], Subscript[u, 2]} /. 
   Solve[eqns, {Subscript[u, 1], Subscript[u, 2]}][[1]] /. Join[signals, D[signals, t]]
```

The answer is that returned by [`AsymptoticOutputTracker`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AsymptoticOutputTracker.html):

```
AsymptoticOutputTracker[asys, {Subscript[r, 1], Subscript[r, 2]}, 
  {Subscript[p, 1], Subscript[p, 2]}] - ans //Simplify
```

> {0, 0}

Comment: I added my code to the question. You can view.

Comment: As far as I understand, if zero dynamic is stable, so feedback-design-based linear methods are valid. And what is the difference between a system with no zero dynamics from a system with stable zero dynamics. What is the fundamental importance in the synthesis of control systems?

Comment: I now calculate the eigenvalues for the residual dynamics, and all the numbers lie in the left half-plane, i.e. the system is stable. What is the difference between a stable zero dynamics system and a complete absence of zero dynamics at all?

Comment: You can understand that by computing the closed-loop system. With no zero dynamics, the dynamics are what you have specified. If there are zero dynamics, those dynamics will be part of the closed-loop system you cannot change them, only hope that they are stable. (If they are unstable, then you have to change the input-output structure of the system and see if they go away.)

Comment: Now it is clear that the presence of zero dynamics will affect the dynamics of a closed-loop system. And if the zero-dynamics is stable, then the theory of linear control can be applied. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: one more small question, rather more as a clarification: how to form an output signal with a derivative, for example $y=\dot{x_1}-x_2$

Comment: You need to modify the model. It may not be possible in cases when the descriptor matrix is singular. But it will work in other cases. You can use [`AffineStateSpaceModel`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AffineStateSpaceModel.html) to get the new model as in `AffineStateSpaceModel[x''[t] == u[t], x[t], u[t], x'[t], t]`.

Comment: I apologize, I probably did not quite clearly put it. For my system (which is given in the start message), I need to form an output in the form: $y=\dot{x}-G$. How it's done?

Comment: If you do `AffineStateSpaceModel[{x'[t] == G[t], 
  G'[t] + G[t] == D[f, {x[t], 1}] + u[t], 
  H'[t] + H[t] == D[f, {x[t], 2}], 
  1/k X'[t] + X[t] == x'[t]}, {{x[t], xs}, {G[t], 0}, {H[t], 
   0}, {X[t], 0}}, {u[t]}, {x'[t] - G[t]}, t]` it results in a system with a singular descriptor matrix. You can try by modifying it further as `AffineStateSpaceModel[{x''[t] == G'[t], 
  G'[t] + G[t] == D[f, {x[t], 1}] + u[t], 
  H'[t] + H[t] == D[f, {x[t], 2}], 
  1/k X'[t] + X[t] == x'[t]}, {{x[t], xs}, {G[t], 0}, {H[t], 
   0}, {X[t], 0}}, {u[t]}, {x'[t] - G[t]}, t]`.